# create path from uri - error- exception thrown in- MultipartUploadRequest- at addFileToUpload(path, "image")

Tags: android, image, http, multipartform-data

I intend to upload image from android to php server. I have commented everything in php file(empty php file). I get exception in MultipartUploadRequest in the line addFileToUpload(path, "image"). I have separated the original function call to multiple parts.
CODE:

```
try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            MultipartUploadRequest a = new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL);
            imageName.setText("ill.exc1");
            MultipartUploadRequest b = a.addFileToUpload(path, "image"); //Adding file
            imageName.setText("ill.exc2");
            //Adding text parameter to the request
            MultipartUploadRequest c = b.addParameter("name", name); //Adding text parameter to the request
            imageName.setText("ill.exc3");
            MultipartUploadRequest d = c.setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig());
            imageName.setText("ill.exc4");
            MultipartUploadRequest e = d.setMaxRetries(2);
            imageName.setText("ill.exc5");
            e.startUpload(); //Starting the upload
            imageName.setText("ill.exc6");

        } catch(IllegalArgumentException exc) {

        }catch(MalformedURLException exc) {
            imageName.setText("malf");
        }catch (Exception exc) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imageName.setText("exc");
        }
```

where path is the String image file path. It is obtained as below.

```
Uri uri;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);


String path = getPath1(Uri uri);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
}
}
```

For the image named "IMG-20210917-WA0002.jpg" in "phone/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsAppImages"; the path is showing as-> "/document/image:1009".  Is it correct?

```
private String getPath1(Uri uri) {
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());//create path from uri
        String path = file.getPath();
        return path;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine

```
private String getPath4(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();

        return path;
    }
```